# Map Dictionary as Model to QTableView

Tags: pyside, model-view

I have a file transfer app that I've been writing and part of it involves a PySide GUI that'll show progress of file transfers. I have dictionary data being passed around while the transferring goes and I'm struggling with which variety of TableView/Widget and AbstractItemView/Model/etc.

In short, I'd like to be able to use the dictionary of data to populate the table and then have the table reflect changing values in the dictionary (like progress %, filesize, etc). Unfortunately ModelViews still elude me and at least a step in the right kind of direction would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance, SO!